# How to make connection to Postgres via Node.js

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I find myself trying to create a postgres database, so I installed postgres and started a server with `initdb /usr/local/pgsql/data`, then I started that instance with `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data` now how can I interact with this through node? For example, what would the `connectionstring` be, or how am I able to find out what it is.

Answer (score 326):

Here is an example I used to connect node.js to my Postgres database.

The interface in node.js that I used can be found here https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@localhost:5432/YourDatabase";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

//queries are queued and executed one after another once the connection becomes available
var x = 1000;

while (x > 0) {
    client.query("INSERT INTO junk(name, a_number) values('Ted',12)");
    client.query("INSERT INTO junk(name, a_number) values($1, $2)", ['John', x]);
    x = x - 1;
}

var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM junk");
//fired after last row is emitted

query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
});

query.on('end', function() {
    client.end();
});



//queries can be executed either via text/parameter values passed as individual arguments
//or by passing an options object containing text, (optional) parameter values, and (optional) query name
client.query({
    name: 'insert beatle',
    text: "INSERT INTO beatles(name, height, birthday) values($1, $2, $3)",
    values: ['George', 70, new Date(1946, 02, 14)]
});

//subsequent queries with the same name will be executed without re-parsing the query plan by postgres
client.query({
    name: 'insert beatle',
    values: ['Paul', 63, new Date(1945, 04, 03)]
});
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM beatles WHERE name = $1", ['john']);

//can stream row results back 1 at a time
query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
    console.log("Beatle name: %s", row.name); //Beatle name: John
    console.log("Beatle birth year: %d", row.birthday.getYear()); //dates are returned as javascript dates
    console.log("Beatle height: %d' %d\"", Math.floor(row.height / 12), row.height % 12); //integers are returned as javascript ints
});

//fired after last row is emitted
query.on('end', function() {
    client.end();
});
```

UPDATE:- THE `query.on` function is now deprecated and hence the above code will not work as intended. As a solution for this look at:- [query.on is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329461/query-on-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Now thats the type of example I like to see.  Clear and inclusive of just enough code.  Thanks JustBob.

Comment: What did you add in your pg_hba.conf to allow connections from node.js? Thanks

Comment: host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5  This entry will if I remember correctly let any IP connect.  Keep in mind this isn't node specific, but PostgreSQL specific.  Also in postgresql.conf I have listen_addresses = '*'. For production setups please read the docs through to make sure you aren't opening holes anywhere. I use this in my dev setup so I'm fine in allow any machine connect.

Comment: The conString parameters spelled out is genius, and just what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: you can install the github-library with "apt-get install node-pg" in ubuntu/debian.

Comment: Careful! ["Client instances created via the constructor do not participate in connection pooling."](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client)

Comment: This script does not work at all for me. I cannot run multiple queries like that. I see three queries, two inside the while statement, one after that and one after the client.end statement. How do I get something like this to work? I want to create multiple tables with one script in my case. Is this even possible?

Comment: this code snippet is based on pg 6.x version or earlier. SO the code for current version(pg 7.x version) is not suitable because pg 7.x adpots es6 syntax and many methods have become obsolete.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: query.on is not a function` so yes it looks like this answer is out of date.

Comment: @NobleUplift ATTENTION:- The `query.on` function is deprecated. So the above code will not work. A solution for that is here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329461/query-on-is-not-a-function

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna Yeah I started using the Promise architecture for Postgres on Node. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is obsolete, and the library is no longer used this way.

Answer (score 36):

A modern and simple approach: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* initialization options */);

const cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
    port: 5432,
    database: 'myDatabase',
    user: 'myUser',
    password: 'myPassword'
};

// alternative:
// var cn = 'postgres://username:password@host:port/database';

const db = pgp(cn); // database instance;

// select and return a single user name from id:
db.one('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = $1', [123])
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user.name); // print user name;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error); // print the error;
    });

// alternative - new ES7 syntax with 'await':
// await db.one('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = $1', [123]);
```

See also: [How to correctly declare your database module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In an ideal world - yes, and yet, the accepted answer here, as you can see above - just the link also. Same as there, it would be just too much to make an abstract from the information the link provides, and considering that both links are given to GitHub's public repositories, the chances of them going dead are not more than the chances for StackOverflow to go dead.

Comment: Maybe just provide a simple example of using it for something very basic, that should only take up a few lines but would be enough to not make it link-only.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, and I just did, hold it off on down-voting :)

Comment: @vitaly-t: Someone probably flagged the post as "very low quality", which gives an automatic downvote if the post is edited or deleted before the flag is handled.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, I hope it's not of very low quality any longer, and I appreciate if you upvote and raise it from the disgrace :)

Comment: The answer has been improved several times. Any chance that somebody reverts the down-vote? It really does answer the question perfectly. Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

Just to add a different option - I use [Node-DBI](https://github.com/DrBenton/Node-DBI) to connect to PG, but also due to the ability to talk to MySQL and sqlite.  Node-DBI also includes functionality to build a select statement, which is handy for doing dynamic stuff on the fly.

Quick sample (using config information stored in another file):

```
var DBWrapper = require('node-dbi').DBWrapper;
var config = require('./config');

var dbConnectionConfig = { host:config.db.host, user:config.db.username, password:config.db.password, database:config.db.database };
var dbWrapper = new DBWrapper('pg', dbConnectionConfig);
dbWrapper.connect();
dbWrapper.fetchAll(sql_query, null, function (err, result) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Data came back from the DB.");
  } else {
    console.log("DB returned an error: %s", err);
  }

  dbWrapper.close(function (close_err) {
    if (close_err) {
      console.log("Error while disconnecting: %s", close_err);
    }
  });
});
```

config.js:

```
var config = {
  db:{
    host:"plop",
    database:"musicbrainz",
    username:"musicbrainz",
    password:"musicbrainz"
  },
}
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Hey, mlaccetti, I have a similar issue trying to connect and run tests against a SQLite3 database.  I'm going through a tutorial with instructions to use DBWrapper, which is why I am reaching out to you.  My question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35803874/1735836

Comment: Node-DBI has been long abandoned since, and no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks, mine was missing `database:` parameter, adding it finally fixed the connection.

Answer (score 5):

One solution can be using `pool` of clients like the following:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
var config = {
    user: 'foo', 
    database: 'my_db', 
    password: 'secret', 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 5432, 
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
};
const pool = new Pool(config);
pool.on('error', function (err, client) {
    console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack);
});
pool.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['2'], function(err, res) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log('number:', res.rows[0].number);
});
```

You can see more details on [this resource](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).

Comment: you did not use 'config'.

Answer (score 3):

### Connection String

The connection string is a string of the form:

```
postgres://[user[:password]@][host][:port][/dbname]
```

(where the parts in `[...]` can optionally be included or excluded)

Some examples of valid connection strings include:

```
postgres://localhost
postgres://localhost:5432
postgres://localhost/mydb
postgres://user@localhost
postgres://user:secret_password@localhost
```

If you've just started a database on your local machine, the connection string `postgres://localhost` will typically work, as that uses the default port number, username, and no password. If the database was started with a specific account, you might find you need to use `postgres://pg@localhost` or `postgres://postgres@localhost`

If none of these work, and you have installed docker, another option is to run `npx @databases/pg-test start`. This will start a postgres server in a docker container and then print out the connection string for you. The `pg-test` databases are only intended for testing though, so you will loose all your data if your computer restarts.

### Connecting in node.js

You can connect to the database and issue queries using `@databases/pg`:

```
const createPool = require('@databases/pg');
const {sql} = require('@databases/pg');

// If you're using TypeScript or Babel, you can swap
// the two `require` calls for this import statement:

// import createPool, {sql} from '@databases/pg';

// create a "pool" of connections, you can think of this as a single
// connection, the pool is just used behind the scenes to improve
// performance
const db = createPool('postgres://localhost');

// wrap code in an `async` function so we can use `await`
async function run() {

  // we can run sql by tagging it as "sql" and then passing it to db.query
  await db.query(sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beatles (
      name TEXT NOT NULL,
      height INT NOT NULL,
      birthday DATE NOT NULL
    );
  `);

  const beatle = {
    name: 'George',
    height: 70,
    birthday: new Date(1946, 02, 14),
  };

  // If we need to pass values, we can use ${...} and they will
  // be safely & securely escaped for us
  await db.query(sql`
    INSERT INTO beatles (name, height, birthday)
    VALUES (${beatle.name}, ${beatle.height}, ${beatle.birthday});
  `);

  console.log(
    await db.query(sql`SELECT * FROM beatles;`)
  );
}

run().catch(ex => {
  // It's a good idea to always report errors using
  // `console.error` and set the process.exitCode if
  // you're calling an async function at the top level
  console.error(ex);
  process.exitCode = 1;
}).then(() => {
  // For this little demonstration, we'll dispose of the
  // connection pool when we're done, so that the process
  // exists. If you're building a web server/backend API
  // you probably never need to call this.
  return db.dispose();
});
```

You can find a more complete guide to querying Postgres using node.js at https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/pg

Answer (score 1):

[Slonik](https://github.com/gajus/slonik) is an alternative to answers proposed by Kuberchaun and Vitaly.

Slonik implements [safe connection handling](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#protecting-against-unsafe-connection-handling); you create a connection pool and connection opening/handling is handled for you.

```
import {
  createPool,
  sql
} from 'slonik';

const pool = createPool('postgres://user:password@host:port/database');

return pool.connect((connection) => {
  // You are now connected to the database.
  return connection.query(sql`SELECT foo()`);
})
  .then(() => {
    // You are no longer connected to the database.
  });
```

`postgres://user:password@host:port/database` is your connection string (or more canonically a connection URI or DSN).

The benefit of this approach is that your script ensures that you never accidentally leave hanging connections.

Other benefits for using Slonik include:

- [Built-in assertions and type safety.](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#repeating-code-patterns-and-type-safety)
- [Safe transaction handling.](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#protecting-against-unsafe-transaction-handling)
- [Safe value interpolation.](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#protecting-against-unsafe-value-interpolation)
- [Transaction nesting.](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#transaction-nesting)
- [Detail logging.](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#slonik-debugging)
- [Asynchronous stack trace resolution.](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#capture-stack-trace)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use [postgresql-easy](https://github.com/mvolkmann/postgresql-easy).
It is built on [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) and [sqlutil](https://github.com/erikman/sqlutil). 
**Note:** *pg_connection.js* & *your_handler.js* are in the same folder. *db.js* is in the config folder placed.

**pg_connection.js**

```
const PgConnection = require('postgresql-easy');
const dbConfig = require('./config/db');
const pg = new PgConnection(dbConfig);
module.exports = pg;
```

**./config/db.js**

```
module.exports =  {
  database: 'your db',
  host: 'your host',
  port: 'your port',
  user: 'your user',
  password: 'your pwd',
}
```

**your_handler.js**

```
  const pg_conctn = require('./pg_connection');

  pg_conctn.getAll('your table')
    .then(res => {
         doResponseHandlingstuff();
      })
    .catch(e => {
         doErrorHandlingStuff()     
      })
```