# Kubernetes service with external name not discoverable

Tags: kubernetes

I'm deploying a nodejs application into a kubernetes cluster. This application needs access to an external database which is public available under `db.external-service.com`. For this purpose a service of the type `ExternalName` is created.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: db.external-service.com
```

In the deployment an environment variable which provides the database hostname for the application is set to the name of this service.

```
env:
  - name: DB_HOST
    value: postgres
```

The problem is that when the nodejs application try to connect to the database ends up with this error message.

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
```

Already tried to use the full hostname `postgres.<my-namespace>.svc.cluster.local` without success.

What cloud be wrong with this setup?

**EDIT:**

- It works if I use directly the plain ip address behind `db.external-service.com` in my pod configuration
- It dose not work if I use the hostname directly in my pod configuration
- I can ping the hostname with one of my pods: `kubectl exec my-pod-xxx -- ping db.external-service.com` has the right ip address

Comment: Did you try with a simple container and `psql`? This destination has TLS?

Comment: Yes, I tried this with a dummy pod. The destination has a self signed certificate.

Comment: So, are you ignoring the certificate when connectin or you import the certificate in a trusted list? With a simple `curl` on the address (with right port), what happen?

Comment: are you able to reach db.external-service.com directly from pod?

Comment: @vasiliAngapov No the dose not work too.

Comment: is the name db.external-service.com resolvable from pod?

Comment: Nope, if I write the hostname directly into the source code it is also not resolvable :/

Comment: please trying to connect postgres from nodejs directly without service for postgres you have created .. something like this env : 
 - name: DB_HOST
   value: postgresql://<username>:<password>@db.external -service.com:5432/databasename

Comment: @Shay Dosent work with the external hostname but when I use the external ip directly

Comment: To sum up, it doesn't work (hostname) with your `nodejs` `Pod` but it works other `Pod`. Could you please share `YAML` manifest of your resources that you are using in this setup? Also I'd reckon this could be the issue of your connection string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802333/nodejs-postgres-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Kubernetes worker nodes are not on the allow list from the database. So the connection timed out.

Answer (score 0):

- Seems like your Pod is not able to resolve DNS db.external-service.com to an IP Address.
- In Kubernetes, Pods use CoreDNS Pods to resolve Service Names to Service IP Addresses.
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/
- If CoreDNS Pods are not able to resolve the DNS to IP Address it is supposed to redirect the request to the Nameserver configured in the Host/VM/Node resolv.conf because dnsPolicy for CoreDNS Pods is Default. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy
- So what is the dnsPolicy of your Pod ?
- Are you able to resolve DNS db.external-service.com to an IP Address from the Host/VM/Node on which the CoreDNS Pod is running on ?

Comment: I have updated the post to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that kubectl exec my-pod-xxx -- ping db.external-service.com is working means that the pod is able to resolve DNS db.external-service.com to its ip. What is the output of command kubectl exec my-pod-xxx -- ping postgres ? Also, can you please provide output of command kubectl exec my-pod-xxx -- cat /etc/resolv.conf