# How to end 'pg-promise' app

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-postgres, pg-promise

I am trying to write a REST API which based on the request payload picks a database and performs certain actions.

As per the documentation, I am releasing the shared connection object at the end of the operation and the follows it through by ending the pgp application.

```
    var pgp = require('pg-promise')();

    var connection = {
      user: 'generaluser', //env var: PGUSER
      database: 'seeddb', //env var: PGDATABASE
      password: '$$$$$$$', //env var: PGPASSWORD
      host: 'localhost', // Server hosting the postgres database
      port: 5432 //env var: PGPORT
    };

    var sco;

    module.exports = {
        getuser: function(req, res)
      {
        Account.findOne({ select: [ 'database' ], where: { appid: req.body.appid } })
        .then(function (result)
        {
          connection.database = result.database;
          var db = pgp(connection);
          return db.connect();
        })
        .then(function (obj)
        {
          sco = obj;
          return sco.any("select * from users");
        })
        .then(function (result)
        {
          console.log(result);
          return sco.done();
        })      
        .done(function ()
        {
          pgp.end();
          return res.ok("Done");
        });
      }
    };
```

Despite of this, I keep getting the below error from the second API call(to the same database) onwards:

```
WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection.
```

Can someone help me with either of the following

- Reuse the pgp connection object on subsequent calls
- Terminate the application properly at the end of each call

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Terminate the application properly at the end of each call

You should absolutely NOT do it, shutting down the whole connection pool after each query is a terrible idea.

> Reuse the pgp connection object on subsequent calls

What's the complication? Are you askign how to reuse objects in Node.js?

See also: [Where should I initialize pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise).

And you should stay away from using method `db.connect` like that, it is not a good way to use the framework. You should rely on the automatic connections instead ;)

Comment: I have implemented a cache layer in the app, to persist db connections across API calls.