# Postgres LISTEN / NOTIFY with pg-promise

Tags: postgresql, notify, listen, pg-promise

I am trying to setup a simple `LISTEN/NOTIFY` functionality in PostgreSQL and notify node.js code using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library.

The pg code I have scaffolded is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%', 'HI';
  PERFORM pg_notify('watchers', TG_TABLE_NAME || ', tags:,' || NEW.tags );
  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER watched_table_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON assets
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_trigger();
```

It does notify on psql console.

However when I use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) code, it doesn't output console messages as I would hope. The relevant node.js code:

```
const pgoptions = require('./pgoptions.config.js');
const connectObject = require('./pgconnect.config.js');
const db = require('pg-promise')(pgoptions)(connectObject);

// added listener code for pg listen / notify
db.connect({direct: true})
    .then(function (sco) {
        sco.client.on('assets', function (data) {
            console.log('Received: ', data);
    });
    return sco.none('LISTEN assets');
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

module.exports = resources;
```

The nodejs code straight out of the [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)'s [Learn By Example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example) documentation [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#listen--notify). I did review the other posts about this topic, but didn't find the [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)-based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not

```
sco.client.on('assets', function (data) {
```

it is

```
sco.client.on('notification', function (data) {
```

i.e. you are subscribing to the generic `notification` message, not to the channel name. That's how it is shown [the very example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#listen--notify) you quoted.

Comment: I made that change and still do not get a notification back. Anything else I should look for?

Comment: @PiyushMehta  It looks like you are raising on the `watchers` channel, while issuing `LISTEN` on channel `assets` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: upvoted! as per the guide here https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Robust-Listeners I keep getting this warning WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection. is this expected

Comment: @PirateApp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise