# PostgresSql + Nodejs (ClaudiaJS) : How to cast array of string to array of timestamp

Tags: arrays, node.js, postgresql, unnest, claudiajs

I am writing API which insert into a table with multiple rows, I am using UNNEST to make it work.

What I have done:

in js file:

```
api.post(PREFIX + '/class/insert', function (request) {

    var db = pgp(dbconnect);

    //Params
    var data = request.body; //should be an array

    var classes = [];
    var starts = [];
    var ends = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        classes.push(data[i].class_id);
        starts.push(data[i].timestamp_start);
        ends.push(data[i].timestamp_end);
    }

    const PQ = require('pg-promise').ParameterizedQuery;

    var sql =
    "INSERT INTO sa1.class(class_id, timestamp_start, timestamp_end) " +
    "VALUES(  "+
        "UNNEST(ARRAY" + JSON.stringify(classes).replace(/"/g, "'") + "), " +
        "UNNEST(ARRAY" + JSON.stringify(starts).replace(/"/g, "'") + "), " +
        "UNNEST(ARRAY" + JSON.stringify(ends).replace(/"/g, "'") + ")" 

    const final_sql = new PQ(sql);

    return db.any(final_sql)
        .then(function (data) {
            pgp.end();

            return 'successful';
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            pgp.end();
        });
}
```

Request body

```
[{
    "class_id":"1",
    "timestamp_start":"2017-11-14 14:01:23.634437+00",
    "timestamp_end":"2017-11-14 15:20:23.634437+00"
}, {
    "class_id":"2",
    "timestamp_start":"2017-11-14 15:01:23.634437+00",
    "timestamp_end": "2017-11-14 16:20:23.634437+00"
}]
```

When I run api in postman, I get the error is:

> column "timestamp_start" is of type timestamp with time zone but
>   expression is of type text

Issue is obviously from ARRAY of string that I used in sql, my question is how to create ARRAY of timestamp for UNNEST, or any suggestion are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: values in array are text, cast array to timestamp array and it will be ok

Comment: Hi, how to cast it? it's my question :P

Comment: `array[]::timestamp[]` or use `cast` function

Comment: yes, it worked, thank you @JustMe

Answer (score 0):

- Never initialize the database inside the handler, see: [Where should I initialize pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise)
- Never call `pgp-end()` inside HTTP handlers, it destroys all connection pools.
- Use static [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) type to generate multi-insert queries.
- Do not return from `db.any`, there is no point in that context
- You must provide an HTTP response within an HTTP handler
- You are providing a confusing semantics for column `class_id`. Why is it called like that and yet being converted into a `timestamp`?
- Never concatenate objects with strings directly.
- Never concatenate SQL strings manually, it will break formatting and open your code to SQL injection.
- Use [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) methods according to the expected result, i.e. `none` in your case, and not `any`. See: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#methods

---

Initialize everything needed only once:

```
const db = pgp(/*connection*/);

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'class_id',
    {
        name: 'timestamp_start',
        cast: 'timestamp'
    },
    {
        name: 'timestamp_end',
        cast: 'timestamp'
    }
], {table: {table: 'class', schema: 'sa1'}});
```

Implement the handler:

```
api.post(PREFIX + '/class/insert', request => {

    const sql = pgp.helpers.insert(request.body, cs);

    db.none(sql)
        .then(data => {
            // provide an HTTP response here
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error:', error);
            // provide an HTTP response here
        });   
}
```

Comment: thanks @vitaly-t about your suggestion, I learnt a new thing. I will try it and get back soon

Comment: The reason I initialised db in handler is: the api is executed by AWS Lambda which has limit time (more less 5 mins), and I sometimes got errors when Lambda expired before. I didn't know how to solve that error properly, so every time api is called, will make a new db connection. If anyone has better approach, please free to share.

Comment: @PeterPham That doesn't make a new connection, just needlessly creates a new connection pool. The pool is capable of creating a new connection when needed. Are you using the latest version of pg-promise?

Comment: I am using latest version of pg-promise. Could you please to give me some more code about how to use pool in this case?

Comment: @PeterPham In a standard way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks to @JustMe,

It worked after casting array

```
var sql =
    "INSERT INTO sa1.class(class_id, timestamp_start, timestamp_end) " +
    "VALUES(  "+
        "UNNEST(ARRAY" + JSON.stringify(classes).replace(/"/g, "'") + "), " +
        "UNNEST(ARRAY" + JSON.stringify(starts).replace(/"/g, "'") + "::timestamp[]), " +
        "UNNEST(ARRAY" + JSON.stringify(ends).replace(/"/g, "'") + "::timestamp[])"
```