# Mocha --watch tests result in database error

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, mocha.js, pg-promise

I have a node.js (v10.8.0) app running express, and am testing it with mocha/chai.  I'd like mocha to run tests every time there is a file change.

My database (postgres) is initialized like this in db.js:

```
const pg = require('pg-promise')();
const db = pg('postgres://localhost:5432/myapp');

class DB {
  createNewUser(data) {...
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development mocha",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js"
  },
```

My tests pass when I run `npm test`.  But if I run `npm test -- --watch`, it will run the first test and pass, but on the first change it will re-instantiate the database and produce the following error:

```
WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Path/to/my/code/src/db.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If this warning were produced in the actual code, you would need to worry about it yes. But in your tests, the situation is synthetic, caused by creation of multiple [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) objects, each containing the exact same connection details.

So here're your options:

- Make sure in your tests that you do not create [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) more than once
- Tell the library not to throw any warnings, by specifying `noWarnings: true` within the [initialization options](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html), i.e. `const pgp = require('pg-promise')({noWarnings: true})`
- Just ignore it, if your tests work.

See also: [Where should I initialize pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise).