# Bulk update to Postgres with node js performance issue

Tags: node.js, pg, pg-promise, node-postgres

I'm facing performance issue while trying to do bulk update in PostgresDB. It's taking more than 180 seconds to update around 23000 records. PFB the code. I'm using pg-promise library. Is there anything I could do to improve the performance?

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

const postgresDBConfig = {
    host: Config.postgresDBHost,
    port: Config.postgresDBPort,
    database: Constants.postgresDBName,
    user: Config.postgresDBUser,
    password: 'pswd'
};

export async function getTransactionDetails(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise<any>(async function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            let db = pgp(postgresDBConfig);
            db.connect();
            let query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
            db.any(query)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("Executed successfully::");
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('ERROR:', error);
                })

        } catch (error) {
            log.error("Error::" + error);
            throw error;
        }
    });
}

export async function updateStatus(result: any, status: string) {
    try {

        let db = pgp(postgresDBConfig);
        //db.connect();
        let updateData = [];
        _.forEach(result, function (row) {
            let updateInfo = {};
            updateInfo["sessionid"] = row.sessionid;
            updateInfo["status"] = status;
            updateData.push(updateInfo);
        });
        console.log("updateData::" + updateData.length);
        const tableName = new pgp.helpers.TableName('table_name', 'schema_name');
        let columnset = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?sessionid', 'status'], { table: tableName });
        let update = pgp.helpers.update(updateData, columnset);
        db.none(update).then(() => {
            console.log("Updated successfully");
        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error updating the status" + error);
            });
    }

    catch (error) {
        log.error("Error in function updateStatus::" + error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code exhibits problems all over the place: 1) [You should initialize the database object only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise) 2) You should not use `db.connect()` at all, which you also use incorrectly for the async code 3) You again incorrectly use async block, skipping `await`, so it doesn't execute correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The code exhibits problems all over the place

- [You should initialize the database object only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise)
- You should not use `db.connect()` at all, which you also use incorrectly for the async code
- You again incorrectly use async block, skipping `await`, so it doesn't execute correctly.
- You do not append any UPDATE logic clause, so it is updating everything all over again, unconditionally, which may be resulting in a delayed mess that you're in.

Here's an improved example, though it may need some more work from your side...

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

const postgresDBConfig = {
    host: Config.postgresDBHost,
    port: Config.postgresDBPort,
    database: Constants.postgresDBName,
    user: Config.postgresDBUser,
    password: 'pswd'
};

const db = pgp(postgresDBConfig);

const tableName = new pgp.helpers.TableName('table_name', 'schema_name');
const columnSet = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?sessionid', 'status'], {table: tableName});

export async function getTransactionDetails(): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const res = await db.any('SELECT * FROM table_name');
        console.log('Executed successfully::');
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

export async function updateStatus(result: any, status: string) {
    try {
        let updateData = [];
        _.forEach(result, row => {
            let updateInfo = {};
            updateInfo["sessionid"] = row.sessionid;
            updateInfo["status"] = status;
            updateData.push(updateInfo);
        });
        console.log('updateData::', updateData.length);
        const update = pgp.helpers.update(updateData, columnSet) +
            ' WHERE v.sessionid = t.sessionid';
        await db.none(update);
        console.log('Updated successfully');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in function updateStatus:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```