# How to call pg-promise helpers.insert function?

Tags: pg-promise

What is the best way to provide 'pgp' to the following function?
Considering 'db' can be *db connection*, *transaction (tx)*, or *task* from the above.

```
module.exports = async (db, tableName, records) => {
  const record_ = records[0]
  const columns_ = []
  for (const c_ in record_) { columns_.push(c_) }
  const insert_ = pgp.helpers.insert(records, columns_, tableName)
  return db.result(insert_, null, r => r.rowCount)
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question about what it is that you are asking? Your question seems quite disorganized, all over the place.

Comment: Question clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Where should I initialize pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise), which shows you:

```
module.exports = {
    pgp, db
};
```

...so you can import it and use whenever you need.

Comment: a) 'pgp' initialized inside package_1 - according to your description within specific module.
Than package_2 uses package_1.
On the top package_main uses package_1 and package_2.
As a result I'm getting valid pgp within package_main, but undefined within package_2.
Can you please advise how it can be resolved?

Comment: I have no idea what package 2 or main package are. The database module has no other dependencies, so if you are running into some dependency loop, that's on your side, and unrelated here.

Comment: And again - this is not very convenient. Sorry to get back!..
According to your approach I need to pass 'pgp' to many functions that are dialing with data. Because it is needed to call 'helpers.insert', 'QueryFile' and others...
Alternative way to obtain 'db.$config.pgp' is hugely helpful but it is valid only for db.  
I highly need the same reference from TX and TASK ! Why it's missing?

Comment: @LeonidMaksimshin Why won't you just return `{db, helpers, QueryFile}` from your database module? That's how modulated namespaces are normally used.

Comment: Such approach works but let me ask:
What the reason of db.$config ? Simplification I guess ?
Is it good practice to have many small routines for data manipulation that have connection in form of db/tx/task - depending on it's place withing program logic ?
So why all three form of connection don't have similar interface to $config ?
After all most set of data manipulation functions are the same...

Comment: @LeMa [The API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#$config) explains why it is there - `to help integrating type Database directly with third-party libraries.` That's why it does not exist within task/tx context. It was not deemed needed, since within the same app anything can be simply exported, while during integration, only the `db` object is typically available.