# How do you do async actions during db initialization in nextjs?

Tags: typescript, next.js, pg-promise

I'd like to create tables on the db initialization stage which look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "created_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
)
```

It would be trivial to do in the normal server setup (even async one), but nextjs doesn't have a centralized "init" stage.
So far I came up with this wrapper:

```
import { setupTables } from "./tables";
import { getDBSingleton } from "./init";


let isInitialized = false;

export async function getDB() {
  const scope = getDBSingleton();

  if (!isInitialized) {
    await setupTables(scope.db);
    isInitialized = true;
  }

  return scope;
}
```

`getDBSingleton()` is the function from this response:
[Where should I initialize pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382796/where-should-i-initialize-pg-promise#answer-34427278)

This wrapper does work, but requires calling `await getDB()` into every single function which does DB call, as opposed to once per module.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution is to move migrations to a separate script and run it before the build.