# how use postgresql with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, postgresql

I am new in JavaScript and i want to create a page which store data in database so please help me and suggest me what i read regarding storing the data ?

Comment: I think it's possible if you use `Nodejs`
Read more:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205496/how-to-make-connection-to-postgres-via-node-js

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the browser, or from the server? As in, are you in a webpage or running something like node.js?

Comment: i use local browser not server.seriously i do not know anything about node.j's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have little knowledge of Javascript and you're trying to have persistent data, I would recommend looking into `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` for the user session.

If, on the other hand, you're looking into storing data to a **proper non-volatile database** like PostgreSQL, but still has got only a bit of Javascript knowledge, I would recommend **Meteor.js**, which is a full-stack Node.js (javascript) framework and is very easy to use.

It does use MongoDB by default instead of PostgreSQL, but for prototyping does the job perfectly.

Have a look here https://www.meteor.com/