# How to make connection to SQLite3 via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am following **The Node Craftsman Book** and have found myself stuck on connecting to the SQLite3 database.

According to the book, I should be able to use DBWrapper and include a path as shown in the screencap of dbSessions.js below:

[image]

I know the database exists, because I'm able to open it using DB Browser for SQLite.

[image]

I know the server is running:

```
Server started and listening on port 8080
```

But when I run my test, it times out.  How can I even tell if I am connecting?  Even though I don't believe I am connecting.

[image]

> **The closest information I could fine is in [mlaccetti's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12304375/1735836).  Perhaps the instructions in the book are incorrect?  Or
>   what am I missing?**

Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var percolator = require('percolator').Percolator;
var dbSession = require('./dbSessions.js');

var port = 8080;
var server = percolator({'port': port, 'autoLink': false});

server.route('/api/keywords',
    {
        GET: function(req, res) {
            dbSession.fetchAll('SELECT id, value, categoryID FROM keyword ORDER BY id',
            function(err, rows) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status.internalServerError(err);
                } else {
                    res.collection(rows).send();
                }

            });
        }
    }
);

server.listen(function(req, res) {
    console.log('Server started and listening on port', port);
});
```

**dbSessions.js**

```
'use strict';

var DBWrapper = require('node-dbi').DBWrapper;
var dbWrapper = new DBWrapper('sqlite3', {'path': '../../data/keyword-wrangler2.test.sqlite'});

dbWrapper.connect();

module.exports = dbWrapper;
```

**apiSpec.js**

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var dbSession = require('../../src/backend/dbSessions.js');
var resetDatabase = require('../resetDatabase.js');
var async = require('async');

describe('The API', function() {
    it('should respond to a GET request at/api/keywords', function(done) {
        var expected = {
            "_items": [
                {'id': 1, 'value': 'Aubergine', 'categoryID': 1},
                {'id': 2, 'value': 'Onion', 'categoryID': 1},
                {'id': 3, 'value': 'Knife', 'categoryID': 2}
            ]
        };

        async.series(
                [

                    function(callback) {
                        resetDatabase(dbSession, callback);
                    },

                    function(callback) {
                        dbSession.insert(
                                'keyword',
                                {'value': 'Aubergine', 'categoryID': 1},

                        function(err) { callback(err); });
                    },

                    function(callback) {
                        dbSession.insert(
                                'keyword',
                                {'value': 'Onion', 'categoryID': 1},

                        function(err) { callback(err); });
                    },

                    function(callback) {
                        dbSession.insert(
                                'keyword',
                                {'value': 'Knife', 'categoryID': 2},

                        function(err) { callback(err); });
                    }

                ],

                function(err, results) {
                    request.get(
                            {
                                'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api/keywords/',
                                'json': true
                            },
                            function(err, res, body) {
                                expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
                                expect(body).toEqual(expected);
                                done();
                            }
                        );
                }
            );

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I get to trying to help, it might be better for you to put up a git repo somewhere with the code; trying to re-create your project from a few files (i.e. the package.json, test, etc.) was time consuming and not something I'm likely to do again.

That said, I did take it for a spin, and think that the most likely scenario is that there is a problem opening the database file.  The `dbWrapper.connect()` is not actually synchronous, so it might make sense to use a callback when establishing the connection to ensure that things are actually alive.  Just for testing purposes, I did the following:

`dbWrapper.connect(function(err) {
  console.log('Connected to DB: ', err);
});`

While I had created the sqlite DB file, the path reference was wrong based on how I was running the application (i.e. `node src/index.js` made the `../data` path that I was using incorrect, and the following error was reported: `Connected to DB:  { [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file] errno: 14, code: 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN' }`

Once I modified the path, it could find the file, and that seems to have worked.

PS - node-dbi hasn't been touched in two years, so might not be the best choice.

Comment: Thank you, mlaccetti!  I did put up a git repository here:  https://github.com/pdlarue/migration_test  According to the tutorial, delete the keyword-wrangler.test.sqlite database (in data folder) and then run the db-migrate up --env test command and the migration should recreate the tables.  When I run the migration I get the following error:  db-migrate up --env test
[ERROR] Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
    at Error (native).  The entire project is up there.  Can you try running it and see if you can find what's wrong?

Comment: I got totally frustrated with this and created another question here.  These two questions may be related.  Take a look and if you put an answer there, I'll give you the points for that one too!!!  :-)  It's here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35807783/1735836

Comment: My path to the db has got to be the problem.  After rewriting everything, I'm hitting your dbWrapper.connect(function(err) { code block and getting Connected to DB:  null on the console.  I don't know where to put it and how to point to it.

Comment: Will take a peek tomorrow.