# Node JS - DB call async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am very new to node js , I used the following link to connect node js with postgres db:

[How to make connection to Postgres via Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205496/how-to-make-connection-to-postgres-via-node-js)

The following code when ran in node console fetches some result from DB (Postgres)

```
var query_str = "SELECT name FROM city" ;
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/cfg";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
var query = client.query(query_str);
console.log(query);
```

But when I put the above code inside function like this and make a function call

```
 function getname()
 {
   var query_str = "SELECT name FROM city" ;
   var pg = require('pg');
   var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/cfg";
   var client = new pg.Client(conString);
   client.connect();
   var query = client.query(query_str);
   console.log(query);
   return query;
 }
```

it returns a empty object. Is it because the code is asynchrnous? If so how can I solve the issue.

Can anyone help me in solve this issue. Or how to proceed further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.query` is asynchronous, your function should expect a `callback`function or it should  return a `Promise`

```js
function getname(cb) {
  var query_str = "SELECT name FROM city";
  var pg = require('pg');
  var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/cfg";
  var client = new pg.Client(conString);
  client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) cb(err);
    client.query(query_str, function(err, result) {
      if (err) cb(err);
      cb(null, result);
      client.end(function(err) {
        if (err) cb(err);
      });
    });
  });
}

getname(function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```