# Migrate SQL data from Hibernate @OneToMany list which used @OrderColumn index but now is replaced by a double-linked list

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

I have two schemas of a DB, both generated by Hibernate, one in which the list of elements inside a `Section` is a `@OneToMany` relation ordered using an `@OrderColumn` and another in which the `Section` elements order is a double-linked list with references to the previous and next elements.
I am now trying to migrate data from the original DB to the new one using a pure-SQL script.

So far I am able to do this for one element of one section, but I cant generalize it for all the items nor all the sections.

(I could manually write the piece for each possible index (there are less than 20 elements per section), but not for all the sections (there are thousands)).

This is the DB Schemas

### Schema 1

**Annotations**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elements")
public class Element {
  private UUID id;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sections")
public class Section {
  ...

  @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn(name = "order")
    private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

  ...
}
```

**which generates**

```
CREATE TABLE public.elements
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  section_id uuid,
  ...
}

CREATE TABLE public.sections_elements
(
  section_id uuid NOT NULL,
  element_id uuid NOT NULL,
  order integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINTS ...
)


CREATE TABLE public.sections
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

### Schema 2

**Annotations**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elements")
public class Element {
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToOne
    private ModelSection section;

  @ManyToOne
    private Element beforeEl;

    @ManyToOne
    private Element afterEl;

  ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sections")
public class Section {
  ...
  (No reference to the elements)
  ...
}
```

**which generates**

```
CREATE TABLE public.elements
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  after_el_id uuid,
  before_el_id uuid,
  section_id uuid,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE public.sections
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

This is the script that updates the `before_el_id` and `after_el_id` of the first two `Element`s of one `Section` (specified by a hard-coded `id`)

```
-- SET THE ID OF THE BEFORE ELEMENT ID OF THE ELEMENT AT INDEX 0 WITH THAT AT INDEX 1
UPDATE elements els
SET before_el_id = (
    SELECT element_id
    FROM OLD_DB.section_elements sec_els
    JOIN elements els
    ON sec_els.element_id = els.id
    WHERE sec_els.order = 1
    AND sec_els.sec_id = 'ac1031fa-5e4d-1452-815e-51cdc32d002f')
WHERE id = (
  SELECT element_id
  FROM OLD_DB.section_elements sec_els
  JOIN elements els
  ON sec_els.element_id = els.id
  WHERE sec_els.order = 0
  AND sec_els.sec_id = 'ac1031fa-5e4d-1452-815e-51cdc32d002f')
);

-- SET THE ID OF THE AFTER ELEMENT ID OF THE ELEMENT AT INDEX 1 WITH THAT AT INDEX 0
UPDATE elements els
SET before_el_id = (
    SELECT element_id
    FROM OLD_DB.section_elements sec_els
    JOIN elements els
    ON sec_els.element_id = els.id
    WHERE sec_els.order = 1
    AND sec_els.sec_id = 'ac1031fa-5e4d-1452-815e-51cdc32d002f')
WHERE id = (
  SELECT element_id
  FROM OLD_DB.section_elements sec_els
  JOIN elements els
  ON sec_els.element_id = els.id
  WHERE sec_els.order = 0
  AND sec_els.sec_id = 'ac1031fa-5e4d-1452-815e-51cdc32d002f')
);
```

### Question

Is there a way to generalize this to, at least, update all the first `Element`s of the lists for all `Section`s?
Is there a way to generalize this to update all `Element`s of all `Section`s?

If this is not possible with plain SQL (I am actually using PostgreSQL), maybe there are some script tools that would help?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a solution for this using SQL only. What I ended up doing was to write a short Node.js program that connected to both databases and run the SELECT and UPDATES inside the program using loops.

Creating a javascript script that connects to two databases is quite easy. I used this as starting point

[How to make connection to Postgres via Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205496/how-to-make-connection-to-postgres-via-node-js)